# why the application hang already use worker?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am trying to use web worker and implement it in angularjs. After implementation I realise that UI hangs; ie. the loader hangs and data is not printed.

Could you please tell me a better way so that the loader may not hang. I know you may suggest to do pagination or lazy loading or virtual display loading.

But why is it hanging now if it is working on another thread.

Here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/zpzIyIicY0Uwmvwxz7du?p=preview

```
function doSomething(){
    var str="<ul>";
    for(var i=0;i<50000;i++){
        str+='<li>'+i+'</li>'
    }
    str+="</ul>";

    return str;

}

self.onmessage=function(e){
    console.log("app.js")

    postMessage(doSomething())

}
```

Comment: Maybe, because DOM insertion is _not_ part of the Worker’s job and inserting 50001 elements may take some time?

Comment: ok...so is there any solution @Xufox ? how to prevent from hanging

Comment: You’ll probably _have_ to do pagination or lazy loading. Never heard of virtual display loading, though.

Comment: without these we cannot remove this problem ..? ok I will check